# ggtags find-definition/reference with IDO interface

Tags: emacs, ctags

I dont like default `ggtags` interface around `ggtags-find-definition/reference/file`. I managed to get `ggtags-find-file` work with IDO, but `ggtags-find-definition` is a lot harder problem.
Is there some package which can do it? If not, how to make one?

NOTE: I want to be able to browse found definitions/references in fuzzy minibuffer, not whole new buffer (and window).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would suggest [ido-completing-read-plus](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-completing-read-plus) (formerly ido-ubiquitous).  It makes almost every command that uses `completing-read` use `ido-completing-read` instead.  However, there is one major case where it doesn't work well: when the completion candidates are generated by a function.  This is the case for `ggtags-completion-table`, which is how ggtags generates its completion candidates.

The [solution](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags/issues/56#issuecomment-43165031) is to define your own `ggtags-completing-read-function` that expands the candidates before passing to `ido-completing-read`.  Note: the reason why `ido-completing-read` (and in turn `ido-completing-read-plus`) doesn't allow this is because it might use a ton of memory and CPU, and may freeze the UI.  You will probably need to tune this to make it acceptable if you have a large number of completion candidates.  Also note that most ggtags commands work with the symbol at point; it seems like you generally just give a prefix arg (`C-u`) to make it prompt for the symbol.

```
(defun jpk/ggtags-completing-read (&rest args)
  (apply #'ido-completing-read
         (car args)
         (all-completions "" ggtags-completion-table)
         (cddr args)))
(setq ggtags-completing-read-function #'jpk/ggtags-completing-read)
```

Comment: Not works, when I hit find-definition, new window is created with buffer filled with found definitions, I dont want this behaviour, I want list of definitions/references in minibuffer with fuzzy matching.

Comment: @Seraph updated my answer with an actual solution rather than a vague meta-solution.

Comment: Not works as expected. ggtags-find-definition display result in buffer, not in IDO minibuffer. Im sorry, maybe, I not specified my problem good enough ...

Comment: @Seraph Use `C-u` prefix, otherwise it will use the symbol at point instead of prompting you for the symbol name.

Comment: Iam fine with using symbol at point, but I want to fuzzy browse in result of this query

Comment: @Seraph OK I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you ran `ggtags-find-definition` and it found results and put them in the buffer `*ggtags-global*`, this function will extract the filenames and line numbers and let you use IDO to pick the one you want.

```
(defun ido-goto-grep-results (grep-buffer prompt)
  (interactive)
  (let (candidates result filename dirname line)
    (with-current-buffer grep-buffer
      (setq dirname default-directory)
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (forward-line 4)
          (while (re-search-forward "^\\(.+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):" nil 'noerror)
            (push (concat (match-string 1) ":" (match-string 2))
                  candidates)))))
    (setq result (split-string (ido-completing-read prompt candidates nil t) ":"))
    (setq filename (car result))
    (setq line (string-to-number (cadr result)))
    (find-file-other-window (expand-file-name filename dirname))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (1- line))))
(ido-goto-grep-results "*ggtags-global*" "Jump to definition: ")
```

This is pretty rough.  You probably want to make your own `find-definition` command that runs `ggtags-find-definition` and `ido-goto-grep-results` at once.  Somehow you need to only get the actual results and not the "Global found N definitions..." line (better regexp, narrow the ggtags buffer, or some other way).

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I will play around with your example and post final solution after I reach it.